# Ethernet & WiFi shows as connected, but internet doesn't work

Tags: networking, lubuntu, internet, ethernet

So on my fresh new install of Lubuntu 17.04, the internet doesnt work. Using Wifi doesn't work and Ethernet cables don't either. They both show as connected & use different drivers. Things to know:

- Pinging 8.8.8.8 works, but pinging www.google.com says something about it not existing.
- I am able to connect to my router's config page
- I have tried changing it from Automatic DHCP to Manuel on both Wifi and Wired
- ifconfig **(net-tools)** isn't installed, but there isn't internet so I don't think I can install it.
- **I'm using another device to type this and all other devices in my house work**

I will add more as I test things. Please help! **Bold things are edits.**

Comment: It would be helpfull if you could show us the routing table that's where I usually start, as it gives an idea of where the traffic is going with sudo route -n

Comment: Also you should be able to use the command ip instead of ifconfig. ip addr show is the command you will want to start with

Comment: @Dam30n Route didn't work because like ifconfig, it isn't installed (Due to net-tools not being installed), but ip addr show does work, it's long so is there a specific part to show or should I just sendthe whole thing (somehow)

Comment: To find the routing table with ip you need to type ip route list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just went from 17.04 to 16.04.3 LTS and everything works now! I guess 17.04 was too new for my computer or something so yeah!

Answer (score 0):

If router does not work properly, especially if it's DNS is not configured correctly, you will have this problem. Sites you contact by the number are OK, ping will even show  name, but you won't get ping from name.

If you turn off auto dhcp/wifi, then you need to put in correct gateway, net ask, and DNS server ip numbers. If you get those wrong, then you get the symptom you have. We used to need that often, but in Ubuntu I have not needed to do it in years.

If the wire does not work, I suspect the router or cable modem devices are set up incorrectly.

Did you check if other computers work within same network?

If truly your system gives no output from this

```
/sbin/ifconfig
```

Then you are really stuck. Something is very badly out of shape. If you can get output, show us.

After a restart, I would open terminal and run

```
dmesg
```

The wifi connect efforts are usually in the bottom. If system is trying and failing, you will see.

Now, if router is proper, we need find out if you lack a pc ether net or wifi driver.  What model/brand do you have? It used to be I had a Broadcom ethernet card that requires drivers that were not included in Ubuntu.

Conclusion. First, the router is probably incorrect. Second, show us /sbin/ifconfig. Third, fix the wire first, it is generally easier. Monitor errors in dmesg output.

Comment: I will try doing these when I get home, but some things to know. I updated the original post with some information you asked like do other devices work(answer is yes) or if it's struggling to connect(answer is no)